# Using time.monotonic function to control an LED matrix in CircuitPython

Tags: python, time, adafruit-circuitpython

I'm having trouble wrapping my head over using time.monotonic() to get a group of LEDs to turn on every half second and turn off every half second repeatedly.  These LEDs are connected through I2C with a matrix driver board and not GPIO pins on a Raspberry Pi Pico. How can I modify the example code below to make it work as I have two functions defined as led.on() and led.off() Assume that the i2c interface has been created

```
import time
import digitalio
import board

# How long we want the LED to stay on
BLINK_ON_DURATION = 0.5

# How long we want the LED to stay off
BLINK_OFF_DURATION = 0.5

# When we last changed the LED state
LAST_BLINK_TIME = -1

# Setup the LED pin.
led = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D13)
led.direction = digitalio.Direction.OUTPUT

while True:
  # Store the current time to refer to later.
  now = time.monotonic()
  if not led.value:
      # Is it time to turn on?
      if now >= LAST_BLINK_TIME + BLINK_OFF_DURATION:
          led.value = True
          LAST_BLINK_TIME = now
  if led.value:
      # Is it time to turn off?
      if now >= LAST_BLINK_TIME + BLINK_ON_DURATION:
          led.value = False
          LAST_BLINK_TIME = now
```

Comment: What's the problem with the above code? Are you getting an error, or is it not behaving as expected?

Comment: I had to step away and think about it for a while.  I was overthinking it and just needed to rewrite some code to make it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thought about it and the answer was simple.  Just needed to take a break.

```
initial = time.monotonic()
while True:
     now = time.monotonic()
     if  now - initial > 0 and now - initial < 0.5:        
         sec_on()
     if now - initial > 0.5 and now - initial <1:
        sec_off()
     if now - initial > 1:
        initial = now
```